# Identical Log Sequence Numbers

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, transaction-log

Below is the log Sequence number of the log back ups and full back ups

Why are LSN numbers same from 11.30 to 11.45 pm...Was it due to the fact that there was no changes made ? When can i find out that the log sequence has been broken ?

```
11.30 pm Log first LSN:  325:31307:1,   last LSN: 325:31307:1
11.45 pm Log first LSN:  325:31307:1,   last LSN: 325:31307:1
12.00 am Full first LSN: 325:31409:239, last LSN: 325:31507:1
01.00 AM lOG first LSN:  325:31307:1,   last LSN: 325:42530:1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Log Sequence Numbers reflect [any and all modifications made to a database](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190411(v=sql.11).aspx).  If no transactions have occurred between two backups, those backups will have the same LSNs.

Having said that, even the action of taking a backup will normally cause an increment to the LSN.

What version of SQL Server is this question about?

Answer (score 1):

> Was it due to the fact that there was no changes made ?

Yes, it's your case.

> When can i find out that the log sequence has been broken ?

You can do smth like this:

```
select database_name, 
       first_lsn, 
       last_lsn,
       lag(last_lsn) over (order by first_lsn) as prev_last_lsn
from msdb..backupset
where type = 'L' and database_name = 'yourDB'
order by first_lsn;
```

In unbroken log backup chain `first_lsn` = `prev_last_lsn` as every next lob backup starts where the previous backup stopped.

In your case the chain is unbroken.

> Having said that, even the action of taking a backup will normally
>   cause an increment to the LSN

This is not true.

Log backup does not write anything to the log.

`Full` and `differential` do write to the log as they always do checkpoint at the beginning, so they write checkpoint operation to the log.

And in fact, after the Full backup in OP we see that the next log backup has changed its LastLSN.